# Making chart on HTML using chart js and external json file

Tags: html, chart.js

So I'm trying to make a chart in html using chart.js and the data are from an external json file.
This is my json file which name is manga140.json

```
[
{
    "cover_title": "Death Note: Tokubetsu Yomikiri",
    "cover_studio": "",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/manga/cover/large/bx115122-HWsbTNeZyoFD.jpg",
    "format": "One Shot",
    "duration": "74%",
    "description": "The chapter will center on Ryuk's Death Note being brought again to the human world, after the end of the main manga.",
    "genres": [
        "Mystery ",
        " Supernatural"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Kakkou no Iinazuke",
    "cover_studio": "",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/manga/cover/large/bx114383-05Uo5j9nIzf8.png",
    "format": "Manga",
    "duration": "64%",
    "description": "Kakkou no Iinazuke's story revolves around 2 teenagers who got switched soon after their birth. Hoping to keep both of their biological and adopted children, their parents decided to engage the boy and the girl.",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Romance"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "MASHLE",
    "cover_studio": "",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/manga/cover/medium/b114960-td2C5YPWPvre.jpg",
    "format": "Manga",
    "duration": "64%",
    "description": "This is a world of magic where magic is used for everything. But deep in the forest exists a young man who spends his time training and bulking up. He can't use magic, but he enjoys a peaceful life with his father. But one day, his life is put in danger! Will his muscular body protect him from the magic users who are out to get him? Powerfully trained muscles crush magic as this abnormal magical fantasy begins!\n\n(Source: MANGA Plus)",
    "genres": [
        "Action ",
        " Fantasy ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
}
]
```

and I have like 30 of them. I try to make a chart that show how many manga that have comedy genre and supernatural genre so i try with this on my html file, but I think I did it wrong because when I opened up the html in browser, it came empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        let data;
        $.getJSON("manga140.json", function(json){
                data = json;
                });

        let comedy = 0;
        let superNatural = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            let genres = data[i]['genres']
            for (j = 0; j < genress.length; j++)
            {
                let value = genres[j].trim()
                if (value.toLowerCase() == 'comedy')
                {
                    comedy = comedy +1
                }
                if (value.toLowerCase() == 'supernatural')
                {
                    superNatural = superNatural + 1    
                }
            }
        }

        let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:['Comedy', 'Super Natural'],
                datasets:[{
                    label : 'Genre',
                    data: [
                    comedy,
                    superNatural
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options : {},
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: When you say, you did it wrong, what does this mean? Whats the current outcome?

Comment: when i opened it on browser, it came up empty